# reloadData of UITableView with Dynamic cell heights unwanted scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to resolve this issue for almost two days ! and I haven't found any solution for it.

I have a tableview with **Dynamic cell heights** for that I'm using this code

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300.0
```

For my tableView I'm using an **[infinit scroll](https://github.com/pronebird/UIScrollView-InfiniteScroll)** library to load more data with dynamic heights.

In some cases I'm reloading my tableview with an updated data ! when I'm calling reloadData() tableview scrolls up or down. to fix that the **estimatedRowheight** should be high at least **550.0**

> tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 550.0

When this problem is fixed I got another issue with the infinitscroll when I'm calling **self.tableView.finishInfiniteScroll()** the tableView scrolls up (Jumpy)

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indxesPath, withRowAnimation:  UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
self.tableView.finishInfiniteScroll()
```

I'm using **AutoLayout** ! and I'm testing on **iOS 9.1**

Comment: you need to set content offset for scrollView

Comment: just to know, from where did you get the value 550.0 and fixed the Jerking Issue? :) It saved my day too.

Answer (score 0):

try this and don't give height to table and cell any where

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 44.0
}
```